# Toggle button active causes function to trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a toggle button, that when active causes a function to trigger.

This function has a timeout attached to it and will retrigger after the given time.

This should only happen when the button is active, so if the user clicks said button again, the automation should stop. In other words the function should `return` if the user has made the toggle button 'inactive'

Here is the code:

```js
function autoSlides() {
  slideIndex++;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  setTimeout(autoSlides, 10000);
}

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  n--;
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    if (slides[i].style.transform == "translateX(100%)") {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    } else if (slides[i].style.transform == "translateX(-100%)") {
      slides[i].style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    slides[i].style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
  }

  if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  } else if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  slides[slidePrev].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
  slides[slideIndex].style.transform = "translateX(0)";

  slidePrev = slideIndex;
}
```

```css
.Slides {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 2s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.Slides-Images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#asktoggle-base {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#asktoggle {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(226, 208, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.active,
#asktoggle:hover {
  background-color: rgb(226, 208, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="Slides" style="transform:translateX(0)">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-1" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-2" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-3" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-4" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<div id="asktoggle-base">
  <span id="asktoggle">toggle slideshow</span>
</div>
```

I've tried creating another `function` and a `do{} while()` loop where said function would add `.active` class to the button then trigger the `autoSlides()` function which would be active for as long as the `.active` class is a part of the button. Running into issues is the bare minimum I could say for this, this *really* didn't work in *several* different ways.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559042/jquery-do-something-when-bootstrap-toggle-button-class-is-active) question, the answer is in jQuery and I would rather avoid using it as the rest of my scripts are in good ol' JavaScript. But if need be I suppose I can do something with that.

Comment: have you looked into `clearTimeout()`?

Comment: @Manav That's a good idea but how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store `var sto = setTimeout();` to a variable then `clearTimeout(sto);`

Here's an example;

```js
var sto = 0;
var isEnabled = true;

function autoSlides()
{
    console.log("called");
}

function toggleMethod()
{
    if (isEnabled)
    {
        sto = setTimeout(autoSlides, 1000);
        console.log("enabled");
    } else {
        clearTimeout(sto);  
        console.log("disabled");        
    }

    isEnabled = !isEnabled; 
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleMethod()">ToggleMe</button>
```

Comment: Could you go into detail as to how I should implement that? Would it be `if` button is active `sto`  `else { clearTimout(sto); }`. Do I make a seperate function to do that check? Please expand on your answer.

Comment: @James9oo0 Pretty much, yes. I've updated my post to demonstrate a generic (since you haven't provided all your code) implementation of this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. We are setting the function to run or not based on the 'active' class.

Info: Snippet will not work here beacause you did not provide your entire code.

```js
function autoSlides() {
    var slidesTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        autoSlides();
    }, 10000);

    if (document.getElementById("asktoggle").classList.contains('active')) {
        slideIndex++;
        showSlides(slideIndex);
        slidesTimeout;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(slidesTimeout);
    }
}

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    n--;
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        if (slides[i].style.transform == "translateX(100%)") {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        } else if (slides[i].style.transform == "translateX(-100%)") {
            slides[i].style.display = "inline-block";
        }
        slides[i].style.transform = "translateX(-100%)";
    }

    if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 0;
    } else if (slideIndex < 0) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }

    slides[slidePrev].style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
    slides[slideIndex].style.transform = "translateX(0)";

    slidePrev = slideIndex;
}

document.getElementById("asktoggle").addEventListener("click", toggleActive);
function toggleActive() {
    document.getElementById("asktoggle").classList.toggle("active");
    autoSlides();
}
```

```css
.Slides {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform 2s;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.Slides-Images {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#asktoggle-base {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#asktoggle {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(226, 208, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}

.active,
#asktoggle:hover {
  background-color: rgb(226, 208, 0);
}
```

```html
<span class="Slides" style="transform:translateX(0)">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-1" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-2" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-3" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<span class="Slides">
  <img src="//placehold.it/1000?text=Gallery-4" class="Slides-Images">
</span>

<div id="asktoggle-base">
  <span id="asktoggle">toggle slideshow</span>
</div>
```